# If $f$ is twice differentiable such that $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=0$, then what can we say about $f''(0)$?

Tags: calculus, continuity, rolles-theorem

The continuity of $f, f'$ and Rolles theorem implies that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$, but is it true that $f''(0)$. We have a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $f''(x_n)=0$ and $x_n \to 0$. But continuity of $f''$ is not guaranteed. Is it true that $f''(0)=0$? Or can anyone give me a counterexample?

Comment: Is it that $f(1/n) = 0$ for all $n,$ or that there's a sequence $x_n$ with $f''(x_n) = 0$?

Comment: Using Rolle's theorem once, you find that there is a sequence $(y_n)$ such that $y_n\to 0$ and $f'(y_n)=0$ for all $n$. Applying Rolle once again, you find a sequence $(z_n)$ with $z_n\to 0$ and $f''(z_n)=0$ for all $n$. However, if $f''$ is not continuous at zero, this does not imply that $f''(0) = 0$. It can be anything. But if $f''$ is continuous at zero, you clearly have $f''(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical example of a function with discontinuous derivative is $g(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $g(0) = 0.$ One can check that for $x \neq 0$ we have $g'(x) = 2x \sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x)$ and $g'(0) = 0.$ It's easy to check that $g'$ oscillates around the origin and takes the value $-1/2$ infinitely often. Picking $f(x) = \int_0^x g(t) \, dt + x^2/4,$ we see that $f''(x) = g'(x) + 1/2,$ so since $g'(x) = -1/2$ happens infinitely often near the origin, we find $x_n\rightarrow 0$ with $g'(x_n) = -1/2$ and so $f''(x_n) = 0,$ despite the fact that $f''(0) = g'(0) + 1/2 = 1/2 \neq 0.$

Answer (score 1):

$$ f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=f(0)+\frac{f'(0)}{n}+\frac{f''(0)}{2n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) $$
Therefore, replacing what needs to be replaced, we have
$$ \frac{f''(0)}{2n^2}=o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) $$
Multiplying by $n^2$ on both sides gives that $f''(0)=o(1)$, by letting $n\rightarrow +\infty$ we have $f''(0)=0$. If you suppose $f$ to be $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$, you can samely prove that $f^{(p)}(0)=0$ for all $p$ by induction.

Comment: Aren't you short of one derivative for the first equality?

Comment: $f$ is twice differentiable thus has a taylor expansion near $0$ of order $2$, am I missing something ?

Comment: Don't we need $C^3$ to control the remainder for Taylor's theorem?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven No, you don't. You only need once differentiable to get $f(a+h) = f(a) + f'(a)h + o(h)$ (not even once continuously differentiable!) and likewise twice differentiable gets you this bound even without any other assumptions.

Comment: @MichaelBarz You are of course right (another case of posting stupid stuff after bedtime). This argument seems to contradict your answer though. What am I missing this time?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven The OP was really asking two questions: One in the title, one in the post. This answer shows that the question in the title, about when $f(a_n) = 0$ a lot, has an affirmative answer. In my counterexample, it's just that $f''(a_n) = 0$ a lot, not that $f$ itself has many zeroes.

Comment: @MichaelBarz thanks for your patience. I see it now